# httpd.conf: BalancerMember can not have a balancer name when defined in a location

Tags: apache

Hi there I am trying to implement a simple load balancing experiment:
Changing between the 3 load balancer scheduler algorithms available for use: Request Counting, Weighted Traffic Counting and Pending Request Counting.

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html
I configured my conf file in apache server as such:

code:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
 LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

  LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
 JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
   JkShmFile     logs/mod_jk.shm
  JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
 JkLogLevel    info
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
  #JkMount  /examples/jsp/dates* balancer
 JkMount /Prototype* balancer
```

# This proxy tag is for Pending Request Counting Algorithm
    
    BalancerMember ip1 loadfactor=1 
    BalancerMember ip2 loadfactor=1

```
 ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests#Request Counting Algorithm
 BalancerMember http://192.168.0.2/ # Balancer member 1
 BalancerMember http://192.168.0.10/ # Balancer member 2
  ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
  </Proxy>
```

However, I keep getting the error:BalancerMember can not have a balancer name when defined in a location

from this line:
     BalancerMember "//192.168.0.2/" # Balancer member 1

Please help

Answer (score 5):

Somehow apache doesn't like the comments at the end of your BalancerMember entries.

If you move the comments on a new line I should work

code:

```
# Balancer member 1
BalancerMember http://192.168.0.2/
# Balancer member 2
BalancerMember http://192.168.0.10/
```

Comment: amazing! Is that documented somewhere in apache doc?